# Where can I find tclConfig?

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to install something that uses Tcl and it requires the config file `tclConfig`. I've installed tcl via `sudo apt-get install tcl8.5` but after doing a search there isn't such a file.

Did I miss a step somewhere?

Answer (score 6):

According to [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=tclConfig&mode=filename&suite=oneiric&arch=any) there is no file named `tclConfig`. A close match is `/usr/lib/tcl8.5/tclConfig.sh` (package `tcl8.5-dev`).

If that isn't what you need please post what you try to install and any error messages you get.

Comment: Awesome. That did the trick thanks for the help!

Comment: You can also try more general package **tcl-dev**. In my case I also needed **tk-dev** for additional files.

Answer (score 2):

Just

```
sudo apt-get install tcl8.6-dev
```

fixes the error!